# Send Text from Textarea in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to wirte an Contactform with the fields name,email and feedbacktext.
Now the Problem. Is it possible, to send the text to an mysql database without switching the site (action=sendtext.php) ?
My Idea was, that the user fll out the form and click on the button 
"submit". In the background send a function the text in my mysql database and give the user an alert("Thanks for giving your Feedback"). How can i do it ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AJAX for making requests without reloading the whole page in j[Query its done by writing](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'service.php',
  data: { a: 1, b: 2 },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

When dealing with a form you might wanna write something like:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(event) {
  // Prevent the form from submitting as a normal form (make full page change)
   event.preventDefault();
   var fromData = $(this).serialize();

   $.ajax({
     url: 'service.php',
     data: formData,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(response) {
       console.log(response);
     }
   });
});
```